# How to execute separate scripts based on list box selections in command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have searched the web for this, and cannot seem to find what im looking for.  I am sure it is because I don't know the terminology (excuse me, I am not the best at coding).

I want to list items in a command line app that a user can select individually.  When they select an item (in my case a site), I want to be able to execute a specific script stored locally for that site selected.  I tried to do a Process.Start line with a sample pdf, but I want to be able to execute specific files based on the items selected in the list the user chooses.  Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListBoxConsole
{
    class ConsoleListBox
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;
            Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(BreakHandler);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.Title = "List Box Items";

            string[] sites = { "site1", "site2", "site3", "site4", "site5" };

            WriteColorString("Choose Site using down and up arrow keys and press enter", 23, 20, ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.White);

            int choice = ChooseListBoxItem(sites, 34, 3, ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.White);
            // do something with choice
            WriteColorString("You chose " + sites[choice - 1] + ".", 25, 22, ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.White);
            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Downloads\insp.pdf");
            WriteColorString(" Press any key to exit", 27, 24, ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.White);
            Console.ReadKey();
            CleanUp();
        }
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry Ken, I have edited the post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class to describe your object.  This is the heart of object oriented programming:

```
class MySite
{
  public string Name;
  public string Path;
}
```

Then, for your particular case you could do something like this:

```
List<MySite> mySites = new List<MySite>();
mySites.Add(new MySite() { Name = "site1", Path = @"c:\a.pdf" });
mySites.Add(new MySite() { Name = "site2", Path = @"c:\b.pdf" });
mySites.Add(new MySite() { Name = "site3", Path = @"C:\c.pdf" });

int choice = ChooseListBoxItem(mySites.Select(s=>s.Name).ToArray(), 34, 3,
    ConsoleColor.DarkGreen, ConsoleColor.White);

WriteColorString("You chose " + mySites[choice - 1].Name + ".", 25, 22, 
    ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.White);
Process.Start(mySites[choice - 1].Path);
```

Answer (score 1):

an if statement

```
if(sites[choice - 1] == choice1)
{
     Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Downloads\insp1.pdf");
}
else if(sites[choice - 1] == choice2)
{
     Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Downloads\insp2.pdf");
}
```